# How to keymap num lk/scr lk to f13 in Debian 10 GNOME?

Tags: linux, debian, asus-laptop, keymap

I have an X551MA laptop that I installed Debian 10 on, and I want to keymap keys I never use (for example, num lk) to more function keys (like f13). How do I do this in Debian 10 GNOME?

Comment: My idea was that when I needed to keymap something, I'd keymap it to the f13 key. Also, I know that windows can handle up to f24 at least. due to a Tom Scott video about the art of the bodge, so I presumed Debian might be able to handle more than f1-f12.

Comment: Ok. However, I'm still going to keep the question up on the matter of in case there's a scenario where it does matter, as a resource people can refer to.